# Oracle JDBC Thin driver : encoding issues

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a dummy function declared in an Oracle DB.

The function was created like this in SQL Developer:

```sql
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE FUNCTION hello
RETURN varchar2 is
BEGIN
  return 'Voici les caractères accentués : àéôï etc...' || chr(10) || 'ça marche ?';
END;
```

My Java application is executed in NetBeans at the moment and goes like this:

```java
try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:OraDoc", "sys as sysdba", "MyPasswd123")) {
    CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{? = call hello}");
    cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NVARCHAR);

    cs.execute();

    byte[] bytes = cs.getBytes(1);

    logger.info(Hex.encodeHexString(bytes));

    logger.info(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    logger.info(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
    logger.info(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
    logger.info(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
} catch(SQLException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    return;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:119 - 0056006f0069006300690020006c00650073002000630061007200610063007400e800720065007300200061006300630065006e0074007500e900730020003a002000e000e900f400ef0020006500740063002e002e002e000a00e700610020006d006100720063006800650020003f
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:121 - Voici les caract?res accentu?s : ???? etc...
?a marche ?
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:122 - Voici les caract?res accentu?s : ???? etc...
?a marche ?
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:123 - Voici les caract?res accentu?s : ???? etc...
?a marche ?
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:124 - Voici les caract?res accentu?s : ???? etc...
?a ma
```

Using the same connection, I ran two different queries to try to understand this issue:

```sql
SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET';
SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters;
```

which yield the following (truncated):

```
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:51 - PARAMETER -> NLS_CHARACTERSET
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:51 - VALUE -> AL32UTF8
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:51 - CON_ID -> 0
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:51 - PARAMETER -> NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:51 - VALUE -> AL16UTF16
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:51 - CON_ID -> 0
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:55 - ==============================================================
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:63 - PARAMETER -> NLS_LANGUAGE
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:63 - VALUE -> AMERICAN
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:63 - PARAMETER -> NLS_TERRITORY
2021-07-20 13:24:36 INFO Main:63 - VALUE -> AMERICA
```

I've tried different things like:

- adding "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8" at the end of the connection string like I do when I connect to a MySQL database
- changing the NLS_LANG to NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8 per [How to setup the NLS_LANG Properly for UNIX](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-nls-lang.html)
- using NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR when registering the outParameter
- adding the parameter -Doracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true

But it's not improving.

For reference, this is my only two dependencies in that project (related to Oracle):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
    <version>21.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
    <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

- I've removed the NLS_LANG environment variable (thanks @Wernfried Domscheit)
- I've switched back to VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR when registering the out parameter a
- I am using getString() (I was using getBytes() to try to see whether I was receiving ? characters or if it was a display issue.
- I've tried to create the string with UTF_16BE charset

Still, the result stays the same:

```java
try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:OraDoc?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8", "sys as sysdba", "MyPasswd123")) {
    CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{? = call hello}");
    cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);

    cs.execute();

    logger.info(cs.getString(1));
} catch(SQLException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    return;
}
```

```
2021-07-20 17:00:20 INFO Main:43 - Voici les caract?res accentu?s : ???? etc...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using `getString` or `getNString`?

Comment: Java does not use the `NLS_LANG` settings of your client, see [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643)

Comment: Use Types.VARCHAR instead of Types.NVARCHAR and getString instead of getBytes. If you use getBytes, try UTF-16BE for the encoding.

Comment: Does your console support unicode?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov oh god, I'm so mad right now. This is literally the first thing I tested but apparently not correctly... It turns out running the java application directly in my bash konsole works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @SayanMalakshinov, I realized that it was a misconfiguration of netbeans.

I added `<Env.JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</Env.JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS>` in the  section of the nbactions.xml file of the project and it immediately worked.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your function is defined as `RETURN varchar2`, not `nvarchar2`, but you are using `cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NVARCHAR);` here. And don't use `cs.getBytes(1)` for strings, use `getString()` instead

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my question following your reply.